# Using regex to ignore an unknown word that is situated between two known words

Tags: c#, regex

I'm just starting to learn regex but there are still quite a few concepts that I'm unfamiliar with. Let's say I have the following string:

```
string s = "a minimum of eight (8) projects over the last five (5) years";
```

How would I ignore the string eight and extract the number between the two brackets (8) when it is placed in front the word projects. I would not want to extract the 5.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you only trying to find the number in parenthesis when it follows the word representation?  Also, what is the upper boundary on numbers you are trying to find?

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what it is you're trying to accomplish? This doesn't make sense to me just yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
string source = "a minimum of eight (8) projects over the last five (5) years";
Regex re = new Regex(@"\((\d+)\) projects");

var result = re.Match(source).Groups[1].Value;
// result = "8";
```

If you need a number, just parse it - `int.Parse(result)`

Answer (score 0):

> extract the number between the two brackets (8)

I'm going to assume your main goal is extracting the number. In that case, the code

```
resultString = Regex.Match(subjectString, @"\d+").Value;
```

will give you the number (as a string). \d is a number, and + means one or more

Comment: This is correct although I guess I should have mentioned that my string could be longer and contain other numbers. For example: "a minimum of eight (8) projects over the last five (5) years" I would only want to grab the 8 not the 5 in this instance. So that's why I'm looking for 8 when it is place infront of the word projects

Comment: What tells you which number to grab? Is it always the first number? Does it always come before "projects"?

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with something like this:

```
String matchPattern = @"a minimum of .+ \((\d+)\) projects";
String replacePattern = @"a minimum of \1 projects";
String done = Regex.Replace(source, matchPattern, replacePattern);
```

What this will do is replace the `eight (8)` in your string with `8`, and it'll do this for any string in that position that's followed by a number in brackets.